# ImportError importing Web3 using pythonanywhere

Tags: pythonanywhere

Using Pythonanywhere, I successfully installed Web3 using the Bash console like so, with no errors:

```
pip3.8 install --user web3
```

My code has the following at the beginning:

```
import json
from web3 import Web3
```

When I run the file, I get an error as follows:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'scrypt' from 'Crypto.Protocol.KDF' (/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Protocol/KDF.py)
```

The same code works perfectly fine on my Pycharm setup.

Any suggestions on fixing this issue?

Comment: I use pythonanywhere all the time. Try `pip3 install web3 --user`. The second error seems to be with pycryptodome. Try `pip3 install pycryptodome --user` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by updating pycryptodom:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --user pycryptodom
```

Everything works fine now.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem, please accept it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I use pythonanywhere all the time. Try `pip3 install web3 --user`. The second error seems to be with pycryptodome. Try `pip3 install pycryptodome --user` as well.

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install --upgrade --user pycryptodome